# Create list of arrays by subsetting single array R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a large 4-dimensional array and would like to subset this array into a list where each element of the list is an array.

Data Example:

```
species<-c("Moose","Deer","Wolf","Bear","Livestock","Human")
unit<-c("A","B")
survey <-1:3
year<-1:3
data <- expand.grid(species=species, unit=unit, survey=survey, year=year)
data$count <- round(rnorm(108,10,2),0)
library(reshape)
data.array <- cast(data, survey~year~unit~species)
```

data.array has dimensions [3,3,2,6]

Looping over the 4th dimension to subset is where I've hit a wall. I would like to subset by the 4th dimension which in this example is "species". Specifically I would like to create a list of arrays for every two species.  As such:

```
array.list <- list()
array.list[[1]] <- data.array[,,,1:2]
array.list[[2]] <- data.array[,,,3:4]
array.list[[3]] <- data.array[,,,5:6]
str(array.list)
```

The full data set has a 4th dimension consisting of 111 species so a solution that can handle an odd number would be best.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the length of the 4th dimension ('n'), get the sequence of alternating elements ('i1'), create an 'array.list' of `length` 'i1'.  Loop through the sequence of 'array.list' and assign each of the elements of 'array.list' with the subset of 'data.array' based on the index we created 'i1'.

```
n <- dim(data.array)[4]
i1 <- seq(1, n, by = 2)

array.list <- vector("list", length(i1))
for(i in seq_along(array.list)){
  array.list[[i]] <- data.array[,,, i1[i]:pmin(i1[i]+1, n)]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed!